# Dataproc how to run a initialization-actions script only on master node and skip running on worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, initialization, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a use-case in which I want to utilize **initialization-actions** in dataproc to run a script that will install the necessary items. I have used a couple of initialization actions scripts on dataproc which work well, and does install on both master and worker nodes. **But here, I would like to run it on master node only**.

Specifically I m installing on top of **yarn** **on master node** ,So that it will automatically install on other nodes (worker nodes).

Is there any flag in **Dataproc Initialization actions** which will skip installing on worker nodes?

Answer (score 4):

Init actions cannot be skipped, but they can include node role specific logic:

```sh
ROLE=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-role)
if [[ "${ROLE}" == 'Master' ]]; then
  #... master specific actions ...
else
  #... worker specific actions ...
fi
```

See this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions#node_selection) for more details.